# schedule a function in odoo from controller

Tags: python, controller, cron, odoo-10

I want to schedule a function which triggers some functionality. The function is written in the controller

```
class SomeClass(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/web/', type='http', auth="user")
    @serialize_exception
    def index(self, data, token):
        some code
```

So now i want to call this function from

> scheduler.xml

file . But my problem here is i don't have any model. So how can i call this function and schedule it periodically???